# How to add a box inside the image using python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, streamlit

I have a code which convert the image into color sketch in that i have added a text(water mark) due to the dark background the text is not properly visible so i need a box with white background so that text would be clearly visible

To display text in bottom right i have did some calculation using width and height

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `ImageDraw.rectangle()` to draw a white rectangle before adding the text:

```
final1.rectangle((x,y,width,height), fill="white")
```

I think some folk call it an *"underbox"*.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to tackle this warning messages DeprecationWarning: textsize is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use textbbox or textlength instead. textwidth, textheight = final1.textsize(text)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what the warning is - I guess we'll have to wait for new documentation.